# local and cloud MySQL database ... 2 way synchronization

Tags: java, mysql, database, synchronization, local

its for a project done in JAVA. I have to synchronize my local database with another one stored on cloud.

my application is normally connected to the xampp and is using the database mysql  (DB NAME : project). 
I have copied another instance of the same database (Project) in the dropBox.
But i don't think it is the proper way of doing this.

can anyone suggest a proper way of doing this synchronization.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: master slave db replication

Answer (score 0):

What you need to set up is the Replication service for MySQL.

[This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) will help.

Thanks!,

@leo

Comment: can u suggest a cloud where i can upload my mysqldatabase ??

Comment: Amazon RDS provides MySQL cloud instances. There you will be able to setup replication services. By the way... what's the purpose of this copy on the cloud. Are you going to access that from an application or its just for backup?

Comment: I just found this (http://xeround.com/cloud-database-comparison/) post comparing several options for mysql on the cloud. Hope you find it useful. Thanks!.

Comment: I guess what you are doing it now (w/dropbox) is the cheapest way. It may not have all the reliability from the methods described previously, but  probably works in some scenarios. Unfortunately all IASS and/or MySQL DB services are payed services at some point.